# After $(window).width() mouseenter is called exponential times.

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a side menu that folds to the right or left, depending on the size of the browser window. On first reload, the mouseenter and mouseleave is called 2 times for each mouseenter and mouseleave. This is not a huge problem.

However, do I resize the window once, no matter how much, the mouseenter is called exponentially; it will be called ~12 times pr. mouseenter and mouseleave, and so on with another resize. Untill the bar becomes laggy because its called so many times.

Here's my code

```
showFloatingPanel = function () {
    //Disables the animation for the tool popups text on mobile devices. For now its enabled for laptops with touch, because they still use mouse.
        if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {


        if($(window).width() < 1250){

            $('.button').mouseenter(function () {
                console.log("mouseenter low res");

                var toolTipLength = $(this).find(".showToolTip").width();
            $(this).stop().animate({width: toolTipLength+90, marginLeft: -toolTipLength-55}, 70);
            $(this).find(".showToolTip").removeClass('invisible')
            ;
        })}
        else if ($(window).width() > 1250) {

            $('.button').mouseenter(function () {
                console.log("mouseenter high res");

                var toolTipLength = $(this).find(".showToolTip").width();
            $(this).stop().animate({width: toolTipLength+55}, 70);
            $(this).find(".showToolTip").removeClass('invisible')
            ;
        })}


        $('.button').mouseleave(function () {
            console.log("Mouse leave");

            $(this).stop().animate({width: "35px", marginLeft: "0px"}, 70);
                $(this).find(".showToolTip").addClass('invisible');
        })
    }

},
```

Comment: Are you calling `showFloatingPanel` every time you resize the window? If so, that's your issue, you're rebinding the events every time you call the method. You need to unbind them before rebinding them.

Comment: Indeed I am. How do I unbind ? $(this).unbind.stop().animate.. ?

Comment: Assuming you have nothing else binding these events to this element, you should be able to just do this at the top of your showFloatingPanel() method: $('.button').off('mouseenter mouseleave'); and the rest should be fine (at least, I'm assuming it will work as mouseenter/leave are meant to be shortcuts to using .on() so .off() should remove them...).

Comment: Thanks, I was having them off after they were called, which didnt work. If you make this an answer, Ill mark it as correct! :)

Comment: Thanks, happy to help - I've expanded my comment into a fuller answer with a caveat about event handlers which you may find useful if you want to bind multiple events to your button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `showFloatingPanel()` on window resize is currently rebinding the event handlers every time, causing the exponential increase you're seeing.

Assuming you have no other methods binding mouseenter/mouseleave to the `$('.button')` element, you should be able to use .off() at the top of your `showFloatingPanel()` method to remove the event bindings and then allow them to be added back in by the method, like so:

```
showFloatingPanel = function () {
  $('.button').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  // rest of your method here
}
```

Note though, if you wanted a different method to also bind to the mouseenter/mouseleave of `$('.button')`, the above would unbind those events too. In that case you would need to bind to named event handlers rather than anonymous functions, something like this:

```
// declare this method outside of your showFloatingPanel() method
function lowResEnter() {
    console.log("mouseenter low res");
    var toolTipLength = $(this).find(".showToolTip").width();
    $(this).stop().animate({width: toolTipLength+90, marginLeft: -toolTipLength-55}, 70);
    $(this).find(".showToolTip").removeClass('invisible')
    ;
})}

// and then from within showFloatingPanel() bind like this
$('.button').on('mouseenter', lowResEnter);
```

The above removes only the mouseenter/mouseleave events bound by showFloatingPanel() so is generally safer.